# Expose input value to tooltip Without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want this layout.
[image]
I don't know what I'm going to do in order to see the value of the input on the bubble in this layout.

The bubble wants to be visible only when it has hovered.

The code is as follows.

```
<div class="control__wrapper">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="4" steps="1" value="4" class="range">
    //<span class="thum"></span> 
</div>
```

```
.control__wrapper{
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
}
.range{
    width:100px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-vertical-align:-10px;
}
.range:focus{
    outline:none;
}

.range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #ddd;
}
.range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 15px;
    width: 10px;
    background: #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -6px; 
}
.range:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Use a `change` event listener that gets the value of the slider and puts it in the text of the bubble.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<span id="valBox"></span>
<input type="range" min="5" max="10" step="1" oninput="showVal(this.value)" onchange="showVal(this.value)"
```

For browser compatibility we need both events

Answer (score 0):

If javascript is ok to use, the you can get the input element and bind an event listener to it. The code below will print out the value after user moves the slider.

```
var inputElement = document.getElementsByClassName("range")[0];
inputElement.addEventListener('input', function () {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have the bubble element already by document.getElementById("*") or document.getElementsByClassName("*"). I call it bubbleEl.

Then you need to define behavior for action hover. You can use oninput and onchange inside  tag or use addEventlistener. In both ways you can pass "this.value" into another function I call showVal(inputValue)

```
showVal(inputVal){
  bubbleEl.innerHTML = inputVal
}
```